# kendo ui - data-column template function is undefined in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I've 2 files: `customer.js` and `add-customer-template.html`. There is a grid on `add-customer-template.html` as given below.

```
<div id="leadsGrid"  data-role="grid" 
                                                         data-bind="source: leadsDS"                                                     
                                                         date-scrollable="true"
                                                         data-editable="popup"
                                                         data-toolbar="['create']"
                                                         data-columns='[                                                                
                                                            {   
                                                                field: "salesPerson", title: "Sales Person", 
                                                                editor: "salesPersonDropDownEditor", 
                                                                template: "#= getSalesPersonName(salesPerson)#"
                                                            }, 
                                                            {field: "date", title: "Date", format: "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"}, 
                                                            {field: "expectedDate", title: "Expected Date", format: "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"}, 
                                                            {field: "expectedIncome", title: "Expected Income", format: "{0:c}"},
                                                            {field: "details", title: "Details"},
                                                            {field: "description", title: "Description"},
                                                            {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;"}]'>
                                    </div>
```

And `customer.js` has 2 functions `salesPersonDropDownEditor` and `getSalesPersonName` as below.

```
var salesPersonDropDownEditor = function(container, options) {
              $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({      
                  dataTextField: "salesPersonName",
                  dataValueField: "salesPersonID",
                  dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "../public/js/salesPersons.json",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                }
                            }
                        }) 
                });
            }

    var getSalesPersonName= function(salesPersonID) {
              for (var idx = 0, length = customerAdd.salesPersonData.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                  if (customerAdd.salesPersonData[idx].CategoryID === customerAdd.salesPersonData.salesPersonID) {
                    return customerAdd.salesPersonData[idx].salesPersonName;
                  }
              }
            }
```

I want to display drop-down list on column `sales person` but I am getting error `salesPersonDropDownEditor` is not defined. When I added "" around `salesPersonDropDownEditor` it's not throwing an error. Now it's throwing error `getSalesPersonName` is not defined.

**How do I call these functions and display drop-down list while editing from grid ???**

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the negatives concerning the use of declarative initialization (i.e. using the `data-` attributes to configure the grid). You'll have to configure your grid in the `customer.js` file so that it is in the same scope as your functions.

**add-customer-template.html**

```
<div id="leadsGrid"></div>
```

**customer.js**

```
$('#leadsGrid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: leadsDS,
  scrollable: true,
  editable: 'popup',
  toolbar: ['create'],
  columns: [
    {   
      field: 'salesPerson', 
      title: 'Sales Person', 
      editor: salesPersonDropDownEditor, 
      template: getSalesPersonName
    },
    // shortened for brevity
  ]
});

var salesPersonDropDownEditor = function(container, options) {
  // hidden for brevity
};

var getSalesPersonName = function() {
  // hidden for brevity
};
```

Comment: I am using mvvm pattern and so I've configured in such a way. How do I call these functions in this pattern ???- @Brett

Comment: I don't have to configure grid in js file- @Brett